# What row-operations allow this $\operatorname{Mat}_{2\times2} (\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & r \\
s & 1 \\
     \end{pmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}
1 & r \\
0 & 1-s \cdot r \\
     \end{pmatrix} = B \quad\quad r,s \in \mathbb{R}
$$
Matrix B is row equivalent to A.
What were the operation that were made on A in order to get B?
Is it possible to do it without dividing row #2 with the parameter $s$?

Comment: $$r_2\leftarrow r_2-s r_1$$

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Even better! I can't believe I didn't see it. Probably it's the late hour!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just multiply the first row by $-s$ and add it to the second row, and you get the matrix $B$.

The row-operation is: $R_2\mapsto R_2 - s \cdot R_1$

Comment: Amazing how simple it gets! But how would you get rid of the parameter `-s` that you created in the first row and first column?

Comment: You can just leave the first row as it was before. The step of multiplying-and-adding can be done in one step, so we do only alter the second row, but not the first. Multiplying $A$ with $\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ -s & 1\end{bmatrix}=C$ from the left side will result in $CA = B$. I recommend reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix

Comment: I think that you should specify the action as follows: $R_2\rightarrow R_2 - s \cdot R_1$ (I'll edit your answer with this - assuming I'm not offending!)

Comment: Yes it was not clear, sorry. I just altered a bit using the $\mapsto$ arrow, which is normally used for rules that should be applied to a concrete element when applying a function.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the first row by $s$ and subtracting it form the second row...